# Transducer's init not called

Tags: clojure, transducer

I am writing a custom transducer as an exercise, but I am surprised to see that its 0-arity init function is not called.

Why?

Is it related to which aggregation function I am using? If yes, which ones would call the init function and why others are not?

```
(defn inc-xf [xf]
  "inc-xf should be equivalent to (map inc)"
  (fn
    ;; init
    ([]
     (println "init") ;; <- this is not called (???)
     (xf))

    ;; step
    ([result input]
     (println "step" result input)
     (xf result (inc input)))

    ;; completion
    ([result]
     (println "completion" result)
     (xf result))))

(transduce inc-xf
           +
           100
           [5 5 5])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `transduce` you can see what happens.

```
(defn transduce
  ;; To get the init value, (f) is used instead of ((xform f))
  ([xform f coll] (transduce xform f (f) coll))
  ([xform f init coll]
   ,,,))
```

Why, however, is more difficult to answer.

Transducers implementing the zero arity is part of the [requirements](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers#_creating_transducers) for a transducer, but it is never actually used in any transducing context in clojure.core. On the mailing list there's been a [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/HK9LkmlRyjY/S0U1u2nQCQAJ) asking the same question as you and [proposal](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/uVKP4_0KMwQ/-oUJahvUarIJ) of an implementation of `transduce` that actually uses the init arity. [The jira ticket](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1569) was declined, however, with the explanation:

> Rich asked me to decline the ticket because the init arity of the xform should not be involved in the reducing function accumulation.
>   - Alex Miller

Why, then, is the init arity part of the contract for a transducer if it's not used anywhere? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I suppose one benefit of having transducers provide a (pass-through) init arity is to enable transforming reducing functions directly, for example `(r/fold (inc-xf +) coll)` … In any case many reducing functions have a 0-arity that provides some initial ‘identity’ value (`+`, `conj`) and a transducer must provide that same arity if it is to fulfil its general purpose of ‘transforming one reducing function to another’.

Comment: Thank you for all this additional information. IMHO, for the implementor of a transducer, it is hard to do anything useful in the init 0-arity while not knowing for sure if it is going to be called. And if the transducer knows that information from the context, it is not fully decoupled.

Comment: A note: I realised today that you mentioned `(f)` while the real question is about calling `(xform)`.

Comment: @Vincent I'm not sure what you mean. I am referring to the fact that `(f)` is called in the current implementation, while I (and you judging by the question) would expect `((xform f))` to be called. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. `(xform f)` and `(f)` have different purposes, `(xform something)` is meant to be called at the end of the transducing process. The question was about why the 0-arity `(xform)` was not called.

Comment: I think we are talking past each other. When I say `xform` and `f` I mean `inc-xf` and `+` in your example. So `(+)` is called, but I'd expect `((inc-xf +))` to be called.